# Is it possible to recover a hard drive which is listed by lsblk but not by fdisk -l?

Tags: hard-drive, fdisk

Having a "dead" hard drive that spins but that is not listed by Linux's "fdisk -l" utility, nor Windows, but which is listed by lsblk Linux command as /dev/sdb, is there any way to make "fdisk -l" find it again?

Answer (score 0):

I kind of had a simmilar drive a few weeks ago, you can try to get as much data as you can by using some recovery tools like ddrescue and sleuthkit. 
If it's empty (or can be emptied) you can try a diagnostic tool from the company's website and try with that.
I managed to recover about 15% of my data, but that was it. 
(tell the kids, dad's external hd is not a throwing toy).